# Пытаюсь реализовать функцию для преобразования строки в обратную польскую запись, но в выходную строки не записываются знаки операций. В чем проблема?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Для преобразования использую следующий алгоритм:

1. Алгоритм анализирует выражение слева направо.
2. Если он встречает операнд, он немедленно помещает его в очередь результатов.
3. Если алгоритм встречает оператор, есть несколько вариантов:

3.1) Если стек операторов пуст, алгоритм помещает входящий оператор в стек.

3.2)Если входящий оператор имеет более высокий приоритет, чем тот оператор, что в настоящее время находится на вершине стека, входящий оператор помещается на вершину стека.

3.3)Если входящий оператор имеет такой же приоритет, верхний оператор извлекается из стека и выводится в очередь, а входящий оператор помещается в стек.

3.4) Если приоритет входящего оператора ниже, верхний оператор извлекается из стека и выводится в очередь, после чего входящий оператор сравнивается с новой вершиной стека.

4. Когда все выражение будет проанализировано, все оставшиеся токены перекладываются из стека операторов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

bool is_number(char ch)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        result = true;
    return result;
}

int prioritet(char ch)
{
    int prioritet;
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '*':
    case '/':
        return 4;
    case '-':
    case '+':
        return 3;
    case '(':
        return 2;
    case ')':
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

string Reverse_Polish_Natation(string input_string)
{
    char ch;
    string output_string;
    stack<char> stek_operator;

    for (int i = 0; i < input_string.size(); ++i)
    {
        ch = input_string[i];

        if (is_number(ch) == true)
        {
            while (is_number(ch) == true)
            {
                output_string.push_back(ch);
                i++;
                ch = input_string[i];
            }
            output_string.push_back(' ');
        }
        else if (ch == ' ')
        {
            while (input_string[i] == ' ')
                i++;
            i--;
        }
       else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        {
            if (stek_operator.empty())
            {
                stek_operator.push(ch);
            }
            else if (prioritet(ch) < prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
            {
                output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                stek_operator.pop();
                if (prioritet(ch) > prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
                {
                    stek_operator.push(ch);
                }
                else if (prioritet(ch) == prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
                {
                    output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                    stek_operator.pop();
                    stek_operator.push(ch);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << output_string << endl;
    return output_string;
}

int main()
{
    string input_string = "5 + 10 * 3";
    Reverse_Polish_Natation(input_string);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например можно сделать вот так:

```
else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if (stek_operator.empty() || prioritet(ch) > prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
                {
                   stek_operator.push(ch);
                   break;
                }
                if (prioritet(ch) == prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
                {
                    output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                    stek_operator.pop();
                    stek_operator.push(ch);
                    break;
                }
                if (prioritet(ch) < prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
                {
                    output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                    stek_operator.pop();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Добавил обработку скобок. Cделал это так: Если встретили ( -помещаем её в стек. Если встретили ), -извлекаем символы из стека в выходную строку пока не встретится (. 
'
if (prioritet(ch) == 2)
  {
     stek_operator.push(ch);
  }
if (prioritet(ch) == 1)
  {
     while (prioritet(stek_operator.top()) == 2)
      {
         output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
          stek_operator.pop();
       }
   }
'
Добавил эту конструкцию. Но что-то идёт не так

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас в выходную строку записывается оператор из вершины стека, только если его приоритет больше, чем у входящего `prioritet(ch) < prioritet(stek_operator.top())`. А условие противного `prioritet(ch) > prioritet(stek_operator.top())` находится внутри этого условия и никогда не выполняется.

```
else if (prioritet(ch) < prioritet(stek_operator.top())) // первое условие
{
    output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
    stek_operator.pop();

    if (prioritet(ch) > prioritet(stek_operator.top())) // никогда не выполняется, т.к. находится внутри противоположного
    {
        stek_operator.push(ch);
    }
    else if (prioritet(ch) == prioritet(stek_operator.top())) // тоже никогда не выполняется
        {
            output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
            stek_operator.pop();
            stek_operator.push(ch);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Решил разделить все условия, но с пунктом 3.4 возникли вопросы, не знаю как компактнее и правильнее записать это условие


`else if (prioritet(ch) < prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
            {
                output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                stek_operator.pop();

            }`